# Determine how to drive and read an unknown three wire pressure sensor

Tags: transducer

This three-wire pressure transducer pinout, drive type, and electrical specifications are unknown. It *should* be a typical industrial transducer. I have tried assuming it is an amplified device with a 0-5, 0-10 V output, or 4-20 mA output. No combination of wiring results in an output signal correlating to applied pressure. Edit Note: I applied 10 bar, which the Agilent 1100 HPLC system easily resolves in normal operation.

[image: Pulse dampeners]

The transducer comes out of a late 1990's designed Agilent 1100 HPLC scientific pump, where it measures the output pressure up to 440 bar (6500 PSI). It is part of a pulse dampener, so I wish to keep it intact. I do not have access to the drive PCB any longer.

The markings are:
Agilent Technologies
Part No. 5065-9907
Revision A
Date code 21/03
PA-23R / 81088  440 bar

I suspect this may be a Keller OEM transducer. Keller's currently advertised lines do not include a 23R, but they follow a similar product naming convention - PA-23R could make sense.

The transducer has three wires in a 0.100 pitch ribbon cable, so unshielded, One is black striped. It is pin 1 in the tables below.

I've monitored the drive (edited) current while powering the transducer for repetitive pulses as evidence of a microcontroller. I also monitored for pulses on the output and power fluctuations during boot time. No evidence of active electronics.

[image: Pulse dampener with pressure feedback]

The only configuration that shows any response at all is #5 below. The output voltage decreases slightly as pressure increases. However, the output voltage depends on the supply voltage. This seems unusual if it is an amplified transducer.

Note: During each resistance check, I cycled the applied pressure between 10 bar and 1 bar (atmospheric).

The pin-to-pin resistance matrix is:

|  | pin 1 (black) | pin 2 | pin 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pin 1 | x | 1.52 MΩ | 13.98 MΩ |
| pin 2 | 1.52 MΩ | x | 11.12 MΩ |
| pin 3 | 13.94 MΩ | 11.08 MΩ | x |

The pin-to-pin voltage drop is:

|  | pin 1 | pin 2 | pin 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pin 1 | x | 1.64<sup>*</sup> V | open |
| pin 2 | 0.73 V | x | open |
| pin 3 | 1.93 V<sup>*</sup> | 1.72 V | x |

<sup>*</sup>Values decreased when attaching the meter.

Powering the transducer with a 15 VDC supply current limited to 60 mA gives this result set:

| Config | pin 1 (black) | pin 2 | pin 3 | current (mA) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | +15 | 0 | out | 43 mA |
| 2 | +15 | out | 0 | 16 mA |
| 3 | 0 | +15 | out | 22 mA |
| 4 | 0 | out | +15 | 0 mA |
| 5 | out | +15 | 0 | 0 mA |
| 6 | out | 0 | +15 | 0 mA |

Comment: I googled Keller and found the following datasheet, manual, and spec:

(1) https://download.keller-druck.com/api/download/feHh39CHy7AhquSGgv3UCS/en/2017-03.pdf,

(2) https://download.keller-druck.com/api/download/8p9KraBomWGhZsPhncEEc/en/2013-12.pdf.

(3) Electrical Connection - GSP Plug EN 175 301-803-A (DIN 43650)

Comment: Throw it in the garbage and buy a new one is my strong recommendation.

Comment: @Andyaka, I have many of these, and they're for test rigs to be shipped to remote workers. Also, there's a lead time problem for this type of transducer.

Comment: which pin is the black wire?  it looked almost like a constant current device... might be worth taking a couple of extra measurements: capacitance and resistance to the outer metal body. and possibly an extra pic closeup of the back where the wires enter the blue potting.

Comment: Pin 1 is the black wire. Good call - edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer***

Keller 23 Connection

[image: Keller 23]

---

***References***

(1) [Keller 23 Datasheet](https://download.keller-druck.com/api/download/feHh39CHy7AhquSGgv3UCS/en/2017-03.pdf)

[(2) Keller 23 Connection](https://download.keller-druck.com/api/download/8p9KraBomWGhZsPhncEEc/en/2013-12.pdf)

Comment: this doesn't match the current measurements.

Comment: @tlfong01, this is what I said I tried within my question (0-10V and 4-20 mA).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you carried out your measurements with the sensor under a few different pressure levels (say 0, 200, 400 bar) showing all the results could provide insight.
2. The symmetry of table 1 suggests a passive sensor (even though the high ohms values of the very same table suggests the opposite: active electronics!).

- If sensor is a variable resistor (maybe 3rd wire is a ground just for noise reduction), or, a dry potentiometer, these cases should be revealed by the measurements I suggested above.
- Ditto if sensor is capacitive (again only 2 relevant wires). Apply a sinusoidal AC to a pin and connect another pin to a resistive load and measure VAC.
- Try to learn if or which passive sensors were in use in the early 90's, especially by Agilent & Keller.

2. I didn't understand your

> I've monitored the drive voltage while powering the transducer for
> repetitive pulses as evidence of a microcontroller.

- If sensor has active electronics with digital interface (open collector output, I2C, UART (USART) / RS-232, RS-485), ofc it would be tough to reverse engineer the RX/TX protocol but if you connected two pins to a DC supply (like you did before) and scoped the 3rd pin (first without, then with, say a 10k pull-up resistor between it and your Vcc, then a pull-down), and also making & breaking the Vcc connection a bunch of times, you might observe some digital activity.
- Again it would be useful to know which 3 wire interfaces were in use in the early 90's, especially by Agilent & Keller.

3. It's not super likely 15V would fry such a unit, but possible (unit could be a custom design for a very specific application which entailed it's being quite fragile), so it might be worth grabbing a second unit and keeping Vcc to 5V.

Comment: I'll do a better job of applying varying pressures. I applied low (10 bar) pressures in the readings above - no change was noted. I've updated the table to include that data.

I sneaked up on the 15V, starting at 5V. After applying 15V, I re-checked the 5V numbers, and they were unchanged. I also checked multiple sensors at 5V - all behave quite similarly.


I have some work to do tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything else, go to a local dentist office and pay them for an X-ray of the sensor, in three radial orientations, roughly 120° apart - mark it on the sensor. That should give you a good idea of what circuitry is present inside. They may need to use a 2-5x longer exposure, depending on how thick the steel is. Anyway, digital X-ray sensors are popular, so on those the results are immediate and exposure can be adjusted quickly.

---

In the configurations that consume power, you’re assuming that the output is voltage. Look at it with oscilloscope: what is it? Does it oscillate? Is it stuck high or low? The output could be current, with a separate supply input. In such case, you’d want to attach a resistance from output to either + or -, and see what voltage you get.

You also should have some idea of the impedance between the pins - complex impedance, at least at a couple of frequencies, and with a couple of DC bias voltages applied. In other words, using a digital RLC meter with DC bias option. The resistances at very low voltages are informative but don’t provide much insight. It’s probably not a passive capacitive sensor, since those should have much more than MOhms between terminals. It’s also not a passive inductive sensor.

A low current curve tracer like the Mr Carlson’s Lab one would be very helpful to see what’s connected to those pins.

For identifying the common/0V pin, it’s worth checking if any pin is connected to the case, perhaps though a “solid” capacitance that would show up when measured. It’s easy to tell apart a real 1nF capacitor from a semiconductor input that happens to provide some capacitance multiplication action and mimics one - as long as you can measure complex impedance and/or can do curve tracing.

There’s nothing unusual about ratiometric outputs, and in fact those would be preferred to a calibration related to a fixed reference voltage. But I doubt very much that the “response” you obtained in config #5 is the real deal. Likely it’s a parasitic path though active electronics. I sometimes see similar behavior with resistive sensors connected to unpowered instrumentation amplifiers.